# django tinymce does not show toolbar

Tags: django, tinymce

i have install django-tinymce and set js url and js root correctly
but as a result it show only a simple text area and doesnt show toolbar and other tinymce features:

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class MyModel(models.Model):
content= HTMLField()
```

i use this:

```
self.fields['content'].widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30})
```

but this not work too! and it show only a simple text area with 80 cols and 30 rows size.

please help me! what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have added tinymce urls to your `urls.py` and loaded media resources in your templates like:

```
<head>
    ...
    {{ form.media }}
</head>
```

There is my django-tinymce config, add them to your `settings.py`:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': 'advanced',
    'relative_urls': False,
    'plugins': 'media',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,|,media,link,unlink,image',
    'theme_advanced_resizing': True,
    'theme_advanced_path': False,
}
```

You can get more details via reading the [docs](http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#configuration).